# How to automatically close browser after launching a download link from Android WebView?

Tags: android, browser, webview

In my WebView, there are several indirect download links which look like `https://www.example.com/download/1234`. When I open the link on computer browser, it downloads the PDF file. When I tap the link on the WebView, it does not download.

Therefore, I set download listener to my webview, and inside onDownloadStart, I use `startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));`

It launches a browser, and the browser starts downloading the PDF file. The browser stays there unless I press the phone Back button.

How to close the browser automatically once the download starts and return back to the application?

Comment: Use download manager instead of webview... Also use full path of file.

Comment: You don't want to open a browser just to download a file from your app when there's a download manager. Google search "android downloadmanager webview"

Comment: I already tried download manager, but the file I got is 0KB. I think because the file has no extension, so download manager download a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

We can't close the browser automatically once the download starts unless the
brower providers the interface to us.
And the reason of  downloading the file  you got is 0KB is not the file having no extension.beacause you just download data from the http response content of the http response message,this has nothing to extension.
So there is another problem when you use DownloadManager.

Answer (score 0):

try to force the download with download Manager : use this code hope it will help you :

```
public void onDownloadStart(String aUrl, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {    
                    fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(aUrl, contentDisposition, mimetype); //returns a string of the name of the file THE IMPORTANT PART
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(aUrl));
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
                    String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie(aUrl);
                    request.addRequestHeader("Cookie", cookie);
                    request.setMimeType("application/pdf");
                    request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath(); //which returns the internal app files directory path
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
                    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)getActivity(). getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    dm.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: you can add also brodcast receiver to open the file once it will be opened

Comment: and you can also check security permissions to Read from external storage to prevent app crashing for the latest android versions .